# Can literal type in C++ contain the only copy constructor having additional parameters with default values?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constexpr

The definition of *copy constructor* from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor is

> A copy constructor of class T is a non-template constructor whose first parameter is T&‍, const T&‍, volatile T&‍, or const volatile T&‍, and either there are no other parameters, or the rest of the parameters all have default values.

And the definition of *LiteralType* from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/LiteralType includes

> ... a type with at least one constexpr (possibly template) constructor that is not a copy or move constructor ...

Does it mean that a class containing *only one* copy constructor having additional parameters all with default values is not a literal type? That would be strange since such constructor is not only a copy constructor.

For example:

```
struct A {
    constexpr A(const A &) {}
    constexpr A(const A &, int) {}
};
constexpr A a{ a, 1 }; //ok everyhere

struct B {
    constexpr B(const B &, int = 0) {}
};
constexpr B b{ b, 1 }; //GCC and Clang error
```

GCC and Clang prints the error in the last line:

```
error: constexpr variable cannot have non-literal type 'const B'
note: 'B' is not literal because it is not an aggregate and has no constexpr constructors other than copy or move constructors
```

while MSVC accepts the code. Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/71YfhfGGG

Which compiler is right here?

Comment: Once you add non-default ctors, you need to add default ctor too. Then it would work. Check [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/M36P8x8h1)

Comment: Does it make sense to have a copy constructor and not a constructor? Isn't A a{a, 1} UB?

Comment: From what I understand, a literal type must have at least 1 constexpr constructor (which is not a copy/move constructor). It may have additional copy/move constructors. In that sense, Clang and GCC would be right.

Comment: _such constructor is not only a copy constructor_ What does it mean?

Comment: @mfnx: `A a{a, 1}` is valid as `void*p = &p;`. Usage of that uninitialized reference is very limited, but OP does nothing with it, so it is ok.